# How can I line up english text in a line containing non ascii (japanese) characters with notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, non-ascii

Here are a few snippets from example lines

```
d5e2306b1afe0724d5798053e430894a       パックマン                                        JPN
9208dd96fcff37400c6f3c42cd1d85ed       スペランカー                                       JPN
```

Its hard to tell but the J in JPN on both lines falls on position 124, yet nothing I can do seems to get them to line up properly.  This document is 500 strong which leaves me with that entire column zig-zag'd all over the place.

Comment: I've edited the post to remove a few spaces so the scrollbar is gone. Before the JPN was hidden and the post did not make sense until I noticed the scrollbars. So technically the position is no longer 124, but the effect is still the same. EDIT: putting it in notepad++ myself, they fall on position 80 now. I only removed 5 spaces, so they were not on 124 in the example anyway.

Comment: If you don't care for the japanese text to be readable, setting the font to Terminal will fix the issue. It will render the japanese as triangles, but all is fixed width.

Comment: correct, i had already pulled it together/condensed it to get them to fit, or so i thought.  It was for illustrative purposes you could say.

I am hoping to preserve the font unfortunately.  what are my other options?  I tried the translate plugin within notepad++ in hopes that perhaps that would be a solution, alas it simply crashed n++ when attempting even a single word.

Comment: Do you mean, preserve the font so you can read the japanese, or because you really like your current font?

Comment: Well ideally both.  but since the japanese already appears "different" i can select all non-ascii characters and I presume change "only" that font somehow?  assuming a font change is pretty much the only solution apart from translating everything one by one or making it illegible?

Comment: Yes, except that notepad++ treats everything as one font, so you have to settle for a font where it works, or move around the text so that the JPN appears in front of the japanese text. The last one possibly can be done using regex, to mass replace the whole though.

Comment: ok, youve offered up several potential resolutions to the issue.  just going to select your first as the answer and play around until i find which one is the "lesser evil" for my use case.

thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. :) It was a fun exercise for me too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the font you are using will have the japanese characters be in a non-fixed width font, and as such the text moves around.

I went through a lot of fonts on my system with the text provided, and the only font that seemed to have the japanese characters as fixed text, was @Malgun Gothic.

So what you want to do is go to Settings, Style Configurator, Go to Global, change the font to @Malgun Gothic, check replace normal font below, and that should do it.

Do note, you can actually change the font and see the result live, so you can experiment with it.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to move the text around. By placing the Japanese text to the end of the row, everything before will be spaced correctly. Using a regex search/replace, you can move all to the back of the file in one go. The only downside is, that the japanese characters are not the same amount of letters, so there will be a spacing difference after the replace, but depending on your document, a second search/replace can fix that.

In Notepad++ Open the search/replace box, in Search for, enter the following regex:

```
^(.+?)([\x{3000}-\x{5000}]+)(.+?)$
```

In replace with, enter the following:

```
$1 $3 $2
```

At the bottom, set it to Regular Expressions

Now hit Replace all.

You can CTRL-Z to undo if the outcome is not desired.

The regex explained:

```
^                                   Start of the line
  (.+?)                             Find any characters non-greedy
                                      and place in capture group 1
       ([\x{3000}-\x{5000}]+)       Find any unicode in the range 0x3000 to 0x5000
                                      and place in capture group 2
                             (.+?)  Find any characters
                                      and place in capture group 3

                                  $ End of the line
```

It moves all unicode characters between the range 3000 to 5000 to the end. It seems the japanese in this example fall within this range.